# Axios Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Hello i am new in nodejs i have this error when i run my app "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80  "
here is my code

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=4dd23b28fb57078c0d5ec9c653e203b2'

axios.get(url)
   .then((response) =>{
       console.log(response)
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: try use `base_url` see this https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `http://` or `https://` at the front of the URL.

Answer (score 7):

You have used a URL without any scheme, that's why axios treating this URL on your localhost that is 127.0.0.1:80. just add **http://** or **https://** before the url.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London,uk&appid=4dd23b28fb57078c0d5ec9c653e203b2'

axios.get(url)
 .then((response) =>{
   console.log(response)
})
 .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
})
```